# PowerAutomate - Condition And Or

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps, power-platform

I'm fairly new to powerautomate. I'm confused on how to implement conditions. I have 4 columns in SharePoint list.

**"OverallStatus", "ComputerStatus", "TelephoneStatus", "DoorStatus"**

Using power automate condition I need to make a decision.

**Scenario 1:**
If ("ComputerStatus", "TelephoneStatus", "DoorStatus") are true then "OverallStatus" is "Approved"

**Scenario 2:** If any of the three ("ComputerStatus", "TelephoneStatus", "DoorStatus") are false then "OverallStatus" should be "Rejected"

**Scenario 3:** If any of the three ("ComputerStatus", "TelephoneStatus", "DoorStatus") are True or "empty/null" then "OverallStatus" to be "Approved"

**Scenario 4:** If any of the three ("ComputerStatus", "TelephoneStatus", "DoorStatus") are False or empty/null then "OverallStatus" to be "Rejected"

I'm not able to figure out how to put together the AND OR combination in the condition. If someone could please place a screenshot of how this can be achieved would be great.

Comment: My suggestion, break it out into multiple.  Looking at that as a single expression will be too hard to follow and support after the fact.  `or(equals(1, 2), equals(1, 1))` is the sort of syntax you're wanting to implement.  Unfortunately, I'm not going to build the whole thing for you, if you show us where you're at with it all re: an attempt, that might make the community want to help a bit more.